# X86 DerivO3CPU CPI Issue

Tags: gem5

I used two_levels.py (The script for tutorial) to run a simulation with `DerivO3CPU` model. The simulation result shows the `CPI` value (cycles per instruction) is lower than 1. I don't think that makes sense to a single-core system.

The only two things I modified in that script are the CPU type (`TimingSimpleCPU` -> `DerivO3CPU`) and the program running (HelloWorld -> A benchmark program).

Did I make the wrong setup for DerivO3CPU or I misunderstand the CPI?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think you can get CPI < 1 because of superscalar execution which DerivO3CPU models. A particularly direct way to see that would be to use the pipeline viewer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I read the document about DerivO3CPU on [https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/cpu_models/O3CPU ], it did not mention about superscalar, so I thought it's not a superscalar processer model. I will check the pipeline viewer. Again, thanks for your help!